# Establish Socket connection between window and iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sockets, network-programming

I need to establish socket connection between window machine and iPads. So here window machine is a sever which can connect to one or many iPad. For window machine(server) code is already there.

So will it be any issue while connecting window machine with iPads using socket?? and what is the best way to do it ?

Comment: If you know how to do socket programming, and you understand how to write whatever protocol the server is using, then no, you won't have any issues. If you don't, you'll have to get a primer on sockets programming, then I suggest reading docs on higher-level abstractions (`CFSocket` etc.) since regular sockets won't cause the cellular radio or WiFi radios to engage. Unless you're doing simple URL requests, its' probably more complicated an answer than can be given on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking for possible issues because one side is Win and the other iOS then you can be sure that's not gonna cause any issues.

Assuming you're talking about iOS TCP client - one good tutorial is here: [iPhone Network Programming](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551).

There is also Robbie Hanson's [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket): well written, easy to implement and comes with examples. Examples are OSX projects but can be quickly converted to iOS projects.